# Manipular uma List dentro de um foreach em uma view

Tags: java-ee, spring-mvc

tenho uma duvida que deve ser simples resolver, mas não estou conseguindo desenvolver uma logica, ou até mesmo possa estar fazendo da forma errada.

Bem, tenho uma tabela na qual eu percorro uma tabela chamada de "categorias" dentro desta tabela eu tenho um relacionamento com outra denominada "destinos" como vocês podem notar abaixo no bean:

**Destination.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="destination")
@Multitenant
@TenantDiscriminatorColumn(name="tenant_id", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER, contextProperty=PersistenceUnitProperties.MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT)
@NamedQuery(name="Destination.findAll", query="SELECT d FROM Destination d")
public class Destination implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_destination")
    private Long idDestination;

    @Column(name="tenant_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Long tenantId;

    @Column(name="appear_website")
    private Boolean dtAppearWebsite;

    @Lob
    @Column(name="description")
    private String dtDescription;

    @Column(name="highlight_website")
    private Boolean dtHighlightWebsite;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String dtName;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_streetview")
    private StreetView streetView;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_video")
    private Video video;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name="fk_category")
    private Category categories;


    //Getters and Setters
```

**Category.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="category")
@Multitenant
@TenantDiscriminatorColumn(name="tenant_id", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER, contextProperty=PersistenceUnitProperties.MULTITENANT_PROPERTY_DEFAULT)
@NamedQuery(name="Category.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Category c")
public class Category implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_category")
    private Long idCategory;

    @Column(name="ct_active")
    private int ctActive;

    @Column(name="ct_name")
    private String ctName;

    @Column(name="tenant_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Long tenantId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="categories")
    private Set<Destination> destination;

    //Getters and Setters
```

Certo! Em minha view tenho um campo no qual exibi o numero de destinos vinculados a cada categoria:

```
<c:forEach items="${category}" var="c">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="editCategory?id=${c.idCategory}">${c.ctName}</a></td>
        <!-- Campo no qual o numero de destinos é exibido por categoria-->
        <td>${categoryHasDestination}</td>
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${c.ctActive=='1'}">
                <td><span class="label label-success">Ativo</span></td>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <td><span class="label label-warning">Desativo</span></td>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Logo, criei um metodo no qual me retorna as categorias e também uma lista do numero de destinos vinculados em cada categoria.

```
@RequestMapping("category")
public String getMenuCategory(Model mv) {
    List<Category> category = dashboardFacade.getCategoryList();
    List<Integer> size = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (Category categories : category) {
        Set<Destination> destinationList = categories.getDestination();
        int s = destinationList.size();
        size.add(s);
    }

    /Retorna uma lista com o numero de destinos para cada categoria
    mv.addAttribute("categoryHasDestination", size);

    //Me retorna todas as categorias
    mv.addAttribute("category", category);
    return "category/categoryList";
}
```

O problema é que na minha view eu tenho um foreach, ou seja, para cada registro a lista é retornada e não o numero em si. A imagem abaixo ilustra o que estou querendo dizer:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agradeço a todos a ajuda

Abraço!

Comment: Já tentou usar o atributo `var` do `forEach` para indexar a lista `categoryHasDestination`? Acredito que ficaria `${categoryHasDestination[i]}` sendo `i` o `var` do `foreach`. A forma como o utluiz citou é mais correta do ponto de vista OO.

Comment: Oi Wakin. Sim a alternativa se duvida é a correta, mas estou usando multi-tenant e acarreta alguns problemas se eu faço dessa forma. Poderia me esplicar melhor a sua alternativa? Muito obrigado

Comment: Olhando melhor a documentação do `forEach`, é a variável `varStatus` que fornece o índice do item na lista. Vou elaborar uma resposta para ver se resolve seu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie um método `getDestinationSize` na sua classe `Category` que retorne o `size` do atributo `destination`.

Aí no seu JSP, basta acessar o método `${c.destinationSize}`.

Comment: utluiz, fiz desta forma, mas como estou usando multi tenant ele me da alguns erros que no momento é complicado de se resolver. Gostaria de alguma alternativa no meu controller para que possa passar como atributo para a view. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @JoãoManolo Não entendi qual o problema com *multi tenant*. O atributo está no model e o escopo dele é da requisição, não vai afetar outros usuários.

Comment: na verdade deu certo sim! O que ocorreu é que no meu mapeamento de destination estava como padrão LAZY. Acabei colocando como EAGER e funcionou tudo perfeitamente. A questão do multi tenant, e que sempre quando ocorre uma consulta no banco eu tenho que passar o tenant_id para saber com qual inquilino estou manipulando. Logo com lazy ele dava problema pois eu não passava o tenant corrente. Como serão poucos registros cadastrados creio que não vai onerar muito o desempenho do meu sistema. Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda abraço e sucesso!

Comment: @JoãoManolo Legal, não sabia dessa questão do *lazy*, mas é interessante saber. Abraço!

Comment: apenas uma ressalva da qual esqueci de comentar. Seu blog e fera! Estava dando uma olhada aqui e os artigos são show de bola. Pode ter certeza de que vou utilizar muito alguns dos artigos publicados.Parabéns!!!

Comment: @JoãoManolo Se tiver sugestões pode escrever pra mim por lá :D

Answer (score 0):

Usando o `forEach` da `jstl` existe o atributo `varStatus` que expõem um objeto do tipo `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagStatus` no escopo da iteração, que fornece alguns dados sobre o objeto que está sendo iterado.

Nesse caso estou usando o `index` para indexar sua lista de `categoryHasDestination` para ter o dado que precisa.

```
<c:forEach items="${category}" var="c" varStatus="status">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="editCategory?id=${c.idCategory}">${c.ctName}</a></td>
        <!-- Campo no qual o numero de destinos é exibido por categoria-->
        <td>${categoryHasDestination[status.index]}</td>
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${c.ctActive=='1'}">
                <td><span class="label label-success">Ativo</span></td>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <td><span class="label label-warning">Desativo</span></td>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Para ver os outros atributos de uma olhada na documentação do [`LoopTagStatus`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html)

Comment: Oi Wakim. Obrigado pela sua contribuição. Na verdade por fim acabou dando certo a sugestão do nosso companheiro utluiz. Mas bem legal esse recurso de LoopTagStaus. Acabei lendo algumas informações e achei bem interessante essa abordagem. Um abraço!